# Eclipse: get a rid of this "mark occurrences" bar?

Tags: eclipse, toolbar

As you may see from the screenshot below it seems I'm having a problem with an eclipse button bar (v4.6 Neon / Linux AMD64). I see a toolbar with a lot of  "Mark Occurences" buttons, there're a lot of them (9) and I don't know how to turn this bar off (disable, customize or hide it). Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance for your kind reply
Ben

[image: eclipse screenshot]

Comment: Try _Window -> Customize Perspective..._

Comment: already tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Replying to myself to solve my own problem but BTW it could probably solve it for someone else as well.
I have had this problem since Eclipse Mars.2 and it seems to be something related to the workspace. Here's what I did:

- Applied tobias_k suggestion
- quit from eclipse Neon
- opened the same workspace with eclipse Mars.2, replyed OK to the eclipse warning message related to version mismatch
- quit again from Mars.2 and reopened with Neon again, same warning message, pressed OK again

After these operations I don't have that toolbar, it seems there's something related to the workspace and after an upgrade it was automatically cleaned